# Terraform AWS dynamic provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am asking whether or not the following pseudo code example is possible in Terraform v14+
If not how else would it be possible to reference a pre-existing provider configuration dynamically?

```
module "mod" {
  source = "../thing"
  account_alias = "test"
}
```

module code:

```
variable "account_alias" {
  type = string
}

resource "aws_some_resource" {
  provider = lookup(aws, var.account_alias, null)
}
```